# Angular 4 installation error

Tags: angular, npm

I am having trouble installing the @angular/cli package

Currently I am running node ver v6.11.2 & npm ver 5.3.0

I first tried to install it using `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` and got the following error which runs in a loop until I ctrl+c out:

```
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
gyp verb command install [ '6.11.2' ]
gyp verb install input version string "6.11.2"
gyp verb install installing version: 6.11.2
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 6.11.2
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/6.11.2
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/6.11.2"
```

After searching for a solution I tried using the work around `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g @angular/cli` and instead get the following errors:

```
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color/-/supports-color-2.0.0.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: update your nodejs to `8.x` will fix this error

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to fix this!

Looks like was NPM installed with wrong user permissions? I used `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local` then installed node-gyp-install, afterwards installed the @angular/cli package successfully!